# Query an array of subdocuments in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents that goes like this:

```
{
  name: "Whatever 1".
  distances: [
    {name: "first distance", distance: 3000},   
    {name: "another distance", distance: 8000},
  ]
},
{
  name: "Whatever 2".
  distances: []
},
{
  name: "Whatever 3".
  distances: [
    {name: null, distance: 6000},   
  ]
},
{
  name: "Whatever 4".
  distances: [
    {name: "hello", distance: 100000},   
  ]
},
```

I need to get all the documents that contains a distance in a given range.

Example: If I query for distance greater than `5000` and smaller than `9000`, I want to get documents `"Whatever 1"` and `"Whatever 3"`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html) to specify range condition for single subdocument of `distances` array:

```
db.col.find({ distances: { $elemMatch: { distance: { $gt: 5000, $lt: 9000 } } } })
```